# Margin-Top is not working for me when attempting to adjust the location of a button

Tags: html, button, vertical-alignment, margins

Margin-top seems to not be working for me. Margin-left is working completely fine. However, when I use margin-top nothing moves. I am trying to move a button vertically (upwards). When i tried using martin-top for a piece of text, it worked completely fine.

I've tried moving and re-formatting the code in several different ways.

```
<a style="margin-left:1180px;margin-top:-310px"><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button></a>
```

I expect margin-top to move the button 310 pixels upwards,but it remains static in the same position.

Comment: Which browser are you using and what is the version of your browser?

Comment: I'm currently using the latest version of Google Chrome on Chrome OS. If I'm not mistaken it's 76.0.3809.111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give `display:block`. It will work

```
<a style="display:block;margin-left:1180px;margin-top:310px;"><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button></a>
```